# js bug in the average function

Tags: javascript

- **I was asked to findout the bugs in this function but I am not able to do...**

  - can you tell me whtats the bug in it...
  - I dont see anything
  - am i missing anythin...
  - providing my code below...
  - I thought return statement should have ;

  function average(a, b) {
        return a + b / 2;
      }

Comment: See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_of_operations for a hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What result do you get from this function, and what are you expecting?

Look into [operator precedence](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Operator_Precedence)

Note that division has a higher precedence than addition. This means that the division is going to happen first, then the addition. This will give you a different result than if the addition happened first.

If you add parenthesis around the addition, you will get the result you are looking for.

```
function average(a, b) { return (a + b) / 2; }
```

Comment: This should be a comment, or, if your rep is too low, put more research effort of your own into this to make it an answer. If you provide the links yourself, it would be more helpful to the OP.